# Ratios of flour-egg-chicken? Simple breading

Tags: chicken, breading

If I am making 1lb of chicken, how much flour, and how much breading mixture, should I lay out to use?

The answer will differ depending on how thick you want the coatings of course, but what's a fair or solid amount?

I'm trying to make breaded chicken strips, but have no idea if I need to use the whole breading box, half the box, etc.

---

Measurements in grams preferred (I'm using a scale). For the eggs, they're Large AA iirc aka 70cal size.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that's the answer you were looking for but maybe it'll be helpful:

Most cooks don't find a reason to measure breading ingredients.

A bowl of eggwash will give you the same coating wether two or twenty eggs are beaten in it. Two beaten eggs and two tablespoons of water go a long way and are usually enough. And the same goes for flour and breadcrumbs: The amount in the bowl doesn't determine the thickness of the coating. It's your hands that do it.

If you're just talking about economy, then allow me to suggest a trick I've seen in restaurants' kitchens: Use more flour and crumbs than you need, and after you're done strain them through a sieve. Pieces touched by eggs will clump and be strained out, and clean flour and crumbs will return to the fridge.